# How should I pass correctly the list parameter? In this way the interpreter gives me error for expected type

Tags: haskell, arguments

I'd like to find the node with the maximum number of children in the list of trees.

I tried passing the parameter as 't' , as a singleton '[t]', as pattern matching '(t:ts)', as '[Tree t]'. None of the above worked.

```
data Tree a = Void2 | Node2 a [Tree a] deriving (Eq,Show)


degree [Void2] = 0
degree [] = 0
degree (Node2 a t) = max (length t) (maximum (map degree t))
```

This is the error that the interpreter gives to me

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Tree a0]’
                  with actual type ‘Tree a’
    • In the pattern: Node2 a t
      In an equation for ‘degree’:
          degree (Node2 a t) = max (length t) (maximum (map degree t))
    • Relevant bindings include
        degree :: Tree a -> Int (bound at Esercizi_Haskell.hs:67:1)
   |
   | degree (Node2 a t) = max (length t) (maximum (map degree t))
```

Comment: `(Node2 a t)` is *not* a list of `Tree`s, you can use `(Node2 a t : rest)` for a list that starts with a node, or `[Node2 a t]` for a singleton list, but anyway, with both, still not *all* patterns are covered.

Comment: So I need to put the value 'a' in the data structure Tree into the list even if it's declared outside?

Comment: what do you mean with "the value `a`?

Comment: Node2 a [Tree a]

The first parameter a. Sorry, I used value instead of parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem to make much sense to define a `degree` function with type `degree :: [Tree a] -> Int`. If I query for the degree of a *list* of trees, I would expect a list of numbers. Especially since that list can contain a lot of different trees that are *not* the subtrees of a larger tree.

It makes more sense to define a function `degree :: Tree a -> Int` to calculate the degree of that specific tree. We can thus implement this as:

```
degree :: Tree a -> Int
degree Void2 = 0
degree (Node2 _ t) = max (length t) (maximum (map degree t))
```

it however contains a problem here: if `Node2` has *no* children, then `map degree t`, will return an empty list, and [**`maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) on an empty list will raise an error. We can however pass the `length t` as one of the elements, like:

```
degree :: Tree a -> Int
degree Void2 = 0
degree (Node2 _ t) = maximum (length t : map degree t)
```

we here thus eliminated the list input from your code, as well as the second clause, since an empty list has no counterpart as tree itsef. The above is indeed a way to calculate the *degree* of a *tree*.

We can here use the underscore (`_`) for the first parameter of the `Node2` data constructor, since we are *not* interested in the value of the node itself.

We could also put more logic in another function `children :: Tree a -> [Tree a]`, like:

```
children :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
children Void2 = []
children (Node2 _ t) = t
```

in which case we can define `degree` simply as:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

degree :: Tree a -> Int
degree = maximum . liftA2 (:) length (map degree) . children
```

Comment: That second definition of `degree` is way cute!